# CopyFiles and PublishBuildArtifacts

Tags: java, maven, azure-devops

I am trying to get some screenshots from juni to azure. This is my yaml file:

```
      #copy files
 - task: CopyFiles@2
   inputs:
     Contents: '*.png'
     TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     OverWrite: true
      
 - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
   inputs:
     PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
     ArtifactName: 'TestScreenshots'
     publishLocation: 'Container'
```

However, I only get

Evaluating: SucceededNode()
Result: False

Answer (score 0):

Please use `PublishPipelineArtifact` task to take instead of `PublishBuildArtifacts` task as a workaround.

The `PublishPipelineArtifact` syntax is :

```
steps:
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/bin/WebApp
    artifactName: WebApp
```

For more info, you can refer to [Publish artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml-task#publish-artifacts).